# replace() function regex fails with "Invalid Character"

Tags: javascript, regex

I use Java

May i know what's wrong with my regex? I hit red line at regex `\`s and stated `Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", [ expected`

```
address.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\.&@#\-,()/\s]/g, "");
```

Comment: If you are using `Java`, then use this. `address.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9.&@#-,()/\\s]/g, "");`.

Comment: The following solution u guys provided. I hit this error `Syntax error on tokens, ArrayLiteralHeader expected instead` ... whole regex with red line

Comment: Java? JavaScript? This doesn't look like Java at all.

Answer (score 1):

You must need to escape the forward slash which is present inside the negated character class. Since js uses forward slashes as regex delimiters, it would consider the unescaped `/` present inside the char class as end of the regex pattern.

```
address.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\.&@#\-,()\/\s]/g, "")
```

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)